# Using image create function

Tags: php, gd

I'm using Creating image function to create an image with exact text message using the following code

```
<?PHP
header ("Content-type: image/gif");
$image=imagecreatefromgif("myimage.gif"); // will be background img
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
$message = "Hello Egypt";
imagestring($image, 4, 25, 10, $message, $black);
imagegif($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

The output should be like this

[image: Hello Egypt]

**Now my question** is there any way i can write image over it not only text
so that if i've flag image at same path (`flag.gif` [image: Flag]) and i would like to write it just after my `$message` to be like this

[image: Hello Egypt Flag]

so is this possible and how could be ! ~ thanks a lot

**Update** 
based on @MarcB idea of using `imagecopy` function

```
<?PHP
header ("Content-type: image/gif");
$image=imagecreatefromgif("myimage.gif"); // will be background img


$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('flag.jpg');// new image will add
imagecopy($image, $src, 120, 10, 0, 0, 32, 20);

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
$message = "Hello Egypt";
imagestring($image, 4, 25, 10, $message, $black);

imagegif($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

the output is not true color WHY :(

[image]

ANY help about this new problem ~ thanks

Comment: http://php.net/imagecopy

Comment: thanks never knew about imagecopy before but i'll try to combine both code hope it works ~ thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcB i've updated the code please view it ! why i'm getting it not true color !

Comment: Since the image is a .gif, the colors you need may not be in the gif palette.  Can you make it a .jpg file instead?

Comment: @SurrealDreams thanks a lot that was very helpful too , i've changed to .jpg and replaced  imagecreatefromgif to imagecreatefromjpeg and it works perfect ~ thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of `Surreal Dreams` and `Marc B`
This one works fine

```
<?PHP
header ("Content-type: image/gif");

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("myimage.jpg"); // will be background img

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('flag.jpg');// new image will add

imagecopy($image, $src, 120, 10, 0, 0, 32, 20);


$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
$message = "Hello Egypt";

imagestring($image, 4, 25, 10, $message, $black);
imagegif($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Output

[image]

I've should have learned the following functions

1. [`imagecopy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)
2. [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)
3. [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Comment: If this is the solution, don't forget to accept it.  It's OK to accept your own solution as long as it the one that works best.

Answer (score 1):

imagecopy() should properly [deal with differences between images' palettes](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.33.html#gdImageCopy); however, the GIF format does not support more than 256 colors, and neither does GD when it works with palette-based images. If 256 palette entries already exist when GD tries to use a new color, GD will pick the closest match, which can produce the results you see.

To avoid this problem, you should use [imagecreatetruecolor()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) to create a 24-bit true-color image in memory. You can then use imagecopy() to insert each GIF image (including the background) and [imagepng()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to generate PNG output, which is better for line art than JPEG, offers better compression than GIF, and can support more than 256 colors.